# Is there any possible to copy files into an existing EAR with Ant?

Tags: apache, ant, jar, copy, ear

Is there any way, any task to make this instruction directly or it is impossible to make this without the sequence: "unzip", "copy" and "jar" tasks ?

I did tried directly with task copy but without success...

```
<copy todir="${ear.project}/servico.jar/META-INF" overwrite="true">
                    <fileset dir="${dir.resources}/r2">
                        <include name="ejb-jar.xml"/>
                    </fileset>
                    <flattenmapper/>
        </copy>
```

Please, i´m waiting for some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [EAR](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html) and [Jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) tasks, like the more general [Zip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) task, have an update attribute which when set to true will simply update rather than overwrite an existing archive.

Comment: But I want to overwrite an existing archive.. Can I reproduct the same idea of task "copy" in the task "ear"? Could you give me one concrete example?